# Haskell there are files missing in the QuickCheck-2.11.3 package

Tags: haskell, archlinux, quickcheck, manjaro

I tried running my program which uses Haskell QuickCheck via `ghc MyProgramm.hs` , but received the following error:

```
$ ghc Ex2.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Ex2              ( Ex2.hs, Ex2.o )

Ex2.hs:21:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’
    There are files missing in the ‘QuickCheck-2.11.3’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
21 | import Test.QuickCheck (
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

I installed `stack`, ran `stack update` and `stack install QuickCheck` without issue but the error persisted.  Then, I ran `cabal install QuickCheck` and got the following errors:

```
$ cabal install QuickCheck
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring QuickCheck-2.12.4...
Building QuickCheck-2.12.4...
Failed to install QuickCheck-2.12.4
Build log ( /home/username/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.4.3/QuickCheck-2.12.4-3d2YDDqfPBn4BfmTJbpJXK.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-9133/QuickCheck-2.12.4'
Configuring QuickCheck-2.12.4...
Preprocessing library for QuickCheck-2.12.4..
Building library for QuickCheck-2.12.4..
[ 1 of 16] Compiling Test.QuickCheck.Exception ( Test/QuickCheck/Exception.hs, dist/build/Test/QuickCheck/Exception.o )
[ 2 of 16] Compiling Test.QuickCheck.Random ( Test/QuickCheck/Random.hs, dist/build/Test/QuickCheck/Random.o )

Test/QuickCheck/Random.hs:10:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random’
    There are files missing in the ‘random-1.1’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
10 | import System.Random
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Test/QuickCheck/Random.hs:11:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random.TF’
    There are files missing in the ‘tf-random-0.5’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
11 | import System.Random.TF
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Test/QuickCheck/Random.hs:12:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random.TF.Gen’
    There are files missing in the ‘tf-random-0.5’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
12 | import System.Random.TF.Gen(splitn)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Leaving directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-9133/QuickCheck-2.12.4'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
QuickCheck-2.12.4-3d2YDDqfPBn4BfmTJbpJXK failed during the building phase. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

However, I already have the arch packages `haskell-random`, `haskell-tf-random` and `haskell-mwc-random` installed.  Does anybody know how to fix this?

Edit: I also ran `cabal install random --reinstall`.

Comment: You'll notice that cabal suggested running `ghc-pkg check`. Did you try that?

Comment: With Stack, you're not really supposed to install packages on your system. Add required packages to the project's `.cabal` file and run things with `stack build`, `stack test`, etc.

Comment: @AJFarmar Yes, I did.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Didn't know that, I'll do it that way in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I have a `main = do` and couldn't get it working that way, I was able to run my QuickCheck test as follows:

To run a quickCheck, first load your program with:

```
 $ ghci MyProg.hs
```

Then to run the quickCheck, find the test you want to run, then run it with:

```
 $ quickCheck my_quick_check
```

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

On Archlinux as of 2022-09-17, `pacman -S ghc cabal-install` will install
system packages that provide only *dynamic* files (`.so`, `.dyn_hi`) in
installed packages inside `/usr/lib/ghc-*`; static files (`.a`, `.hi`) are (for
the most part) missing.  However, the default cabal configuration *enables* static file
building.  Unfortunately, upstream cabal-install doesn't track whether or not
static files are available inside installed packages.  It just assumes they
are, and when they are gone, it fails with errors such as you have found:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, ../setup.dist/work/depender/dist/build/depender/depender-tmp/Main.o )

Main.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module `Dynamic'
    There are files missing in the `dynamic-1.0' package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
  | import qualified Dynamic (number)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

## Workaround

A quick workaround just to get up and running quickly is to disable static file
building, which is by default enabled.  (Note that trying to pass package-local
flags to disable static file with e.g. `--enable-shared --enable-executable-dynamic --disable-library-vanilla` (which is how most if
not all current Archlinux Haskell packages seem to build packages, e.g. with
https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-community/blob/master/haskell-scientific/trunk/PKGBUILD)
building using `cabal-install` may be ignored due to another, related bug; but
`~/.cabal/config` is a safe bet.)  You may do so by adding 3 lines to
`~/.cabal/config` in the appropriate location:

```
library-vanilla: False
shared: True
executable-dynamic: True
```

(Alternatively, consider using alternative tools like `stack`.)

## More complete solution

For a more long-term solution, one option involves 2 pieces: 1) one or more
system packages that provide all types of build artifacts, static and dynamic,
for the base, foundational packages (from GHC and cabal-install), at least as an option besides dynamic-only packages (secondary Haskell packages are optional,
since cabal-install can rebuild these with needed build artifacts (static or
dynamic)), and 2) patching cabal-install (and ghc-pkg, which can handle `.conf`
files recording information about installed packages) to track whether static
files are available, and to be aware of these when resolving dependencies so
that cabal-install knows when to prefer rebuild a source package with needed
build artifact configuration over an already installed package that doesn't
provid required build artifacts.

There is a merge request (I submitted) that provides such a patchset, called
`fix-dynamic-deps`, at https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/8461.  For users
running into exactly the problem that you described (myself included), I also
created an AUR package that provides both pieces based on GHC 9.4.2 with Cabal
3.9.0.0 that includes my patchset (there is a mirror at
https://github.com/bairyn/ghc-cabal-arts.)  It provides `ghc` and
`cabal-install` but includes both of these pieces.

## Further reading

Here are a few more resources I wrote on or are related to this bug:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Haskell&diff=745459&oldid=738269#Troubleshooting
- https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/8461
- https://github.com/bairyn/ghc-cabal-arts
- https://github.com/bairyn/cabal/tree/fix-dynamic-builds